# PHP same namespace for several classes

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I wanted a clarification on the use of namespaces.

If I have two classes in the same namespace, like this:

```
<?php

namespace Test\Collection; 

class First{}
```

And:

```
<?php

namespace Test\Collection; 

class Second{}
```

In this case I can use them in this way?

```
use Test\Collection;

$first = new First();
$second = new Second();
```

Thanks.

Comment: And the question is? Why don't you simply test it yourself and see

Comment: I tried it, and it does not work as it should specify the class name in the namespace to use, so I wanted to know if there was another way to do this, that I will not include any namespace, but I want to include a single namespace and use all classes. I'm sorry for my english.
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use multiple classes of a namespace like below

```
use Test\Collection as Container;

$first = new Container\First();
$second = new Container\Second();
```

I think second solution from @Will may not work at some cases.

for your better understanding take a look at this [explanation](http://daylerees.com/php-namespaces-explained/). Hope this helps

Answer (score 8):

Not quite.

With your example, you'd need:

```
<?php

use Test\Collection\First;
use Test\Collection\Second;

$first = new First();
$second = new Second();
```

Or:

```
<?php

use Test\Collection;

$first = new Collection\First();
$second = new Collection\Second();
```

See [the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) for more information. This is known as "namespace importing or aliasing".

Comment: Thank you, it was what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone interested in doing this from PHP 7 onwards, there is another option:

*"From PHP 7.0 onwards, classes, functions and constants being imported from the same namespace can be grouped together in a single use statement"*

```
use some\namespace\{ClassA, ClassB, ClassC as C};
use function some\namespace\{fn_a, fn_b, fn_c};
use const some\namespace\{ConstA, ConstB, ConstC};
```

Source: [Official PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.group)